# Custom standalone gradle Plugins aren't as powerful as usual build.gradle code?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

Sorry if this seems to be a foolish question. But I'm a beginner in Java and Gradle and I am really having this problems with the 'Gradle Docs' sometimes.

I just want to find an easy way to reuse code from my project's `build.gradle` file. So packing this code into a plugin that is uploaded and versioned in my company repo seemed to be ideal. But those standalone plugins are `java/groovy` `projects/programs` with different syntax than the gradle DSL. So they don't facilitate the same possibilities and closures as in a gradle.build file, right?

For example if i wanted a repositories closure to be reusable, looking like this:

```
repositories {
maven {
    url project.Repo_GP_Internal
    credentials {
        username project.Repo_GP_User
        }
    }
}
```

or the uploadArchives closure:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: Repo_Upload_Internal){
                authentication(userName: project.Repo_Upload_User, password: project.Repo_Upload_Pass)
            }        
            snapshotRepository(url: Repo_Upload_Snapshot){
                authentication(userName: project.Repo_Upload_User, password: project.Repo_Upload_Pass)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can I pack this in any way into a plugin which can be uploaded to my repo as a jar? As you see it's about code from the configuration phase.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely can use every feature available to you in build.gradle from plugin as well.

The build.gradle file is essentially just a groovy script executed with project object set as a delegate and most magic words you use in it (like `task`) are just methods of the [Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) class. The most significant difference is that in your custom plugin or task you have to interact with project explicitly.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.repositories {
            maven {
                url project.Repo_GP_Internal
                credentials {
                    username project.Repo_GP_User
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For methods available inside the `repositories` closure, see [documentation for RepositoryHandler](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/RepositoryHandler.html)

Of course, there's still the question of how your project will be accessing your plugin. For example, it may be retrieving it from a maven repository, in which case you would need to define `buildscript { repositories {` with that maven repository parameters explicitly in each project.

Comment: Thank you! With this explanation I will surely achive my goals.

Answer (score 0):

I want to post something in addition to Andrei's answer, after i struggled with reading the properties in the plugin from a `gradle.properties` file. It's this code:

```
Properties props = new Properties()
props.load(new FileInputStream("gradle.properties"))
```

then you can access the properties like this: `props.Repo_GP_Internal`

Comment: That's strange: you shouldn't need to bother reading those yourself. Instead Gradle should parse user.home/gradle.properties and project.dir/gradle.properties and make properties from these files accessible as project.myProperty. But it will fail if a property is not set in neither of the files, in which case you can use project.property("myProperty") to safely get its value.

Comment: Must be some Stackoverflow magic or something. I tried just like you wrote, to access the properties like `project.myProperty`. Double checked spelling and everything. It didn't work. Now after I tried it again it's totally working... thanks again